# Drawing 3D bar charts using Highcharts through JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, 3d, bar-chart

I want to draw a 3D stacked and grouped bar chart using highcharts and please find the below code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 15,
            beta: 15,
            viewDistance: 25,
            depth: 40
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumption, grouped by gender'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
        labels: {
            skew3d: true,
            style: {
                fontSize: '16px'
            }
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Number of fruits',
            skew3d: true
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.key}</b><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: {point.y} / {point.stackTotal}'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            depth: 40
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
        stack: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
        stack: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
        stack: 'female'
    }, {
        name: 'Janet',
        data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
        stack: 'female'
    }]
});
```

I downloaded all highchart.js, highchart-3d.js, export.js and export-data.js files and manually imported the files. But the following output is received

[image]

The 3D look is missing although the chart is drawn correctly. Can I know why ?

Comment: Please check if `highchart-3d.js` is loaded correctly. In the console type `Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.element3d` and check if it is not undefined. If not it should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the issue is, however, I recreated your graph in the JSFiddle below, feel free to copy and paste it. The original was taken from https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/3d-charts, I simply added your code into it and it worked. Heres the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ameer_Hamoodi/v6u30ect/4/. 
Here's the code:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 15,
            beta: 15,
            viewDistance: 25,
            depth: 40
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumption, grouped by gender'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
        labels: {
            skew3d: true,
            style: {
                fontSize: '16px'
            }
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Number of fruits',
            skew3d: true
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.key}</b><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: {point.y} / {point.stackTotal}'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            depth: 40
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
        stack: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
        stack: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
        stack: 'female'
    }, {
        name: 'Janet',
        data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
        stack: 'female'
    }]
});
```

```css
#container, #sliders {
    min-width: 310px; 
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#container {
    height: 400px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="sliders">
    <table>
        <tr>
         <td>Alpha Angle</td>
         <td><input id="alpha" type="range" min="0" max="45" value="15"/> <span id="alpha-value" class="value"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Beta Angle</td>
         <td><input id="beta" type="range" min="-45" max="45" value="15"/> <span id="beta-value" class="value"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Depth</td>
         <td><input id="depth" type="range" min="20" max="100" value="50"/> <span id="depth-value" class="value"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I hope this helps!